# Requirements for installing Windows Installer Package (.msi) on Client Pc

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project, advanced-installer

I am trying to install my .msi application on a client Pc.
After installed  it on my Personal computer it worked correctly without any problem but after installing it on other client pc some fonts and images are missing and also SQL server database does not work
which mean that those fonts are not installed on client pc so that
**My question is:**
Is there any way to install all used fonts on client pc during the installation of .msi on client pc ?

and what are the requirements for installing .msi on other client pc ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This needs more detail. If there are missing images, are you explicitly installing them? Or assuming they get installed somehow? Which fonts are missing? Fonts are mostly part of the OS so it's not obvious what you mean by "missing". If your SQL Server database does not work, what does that mean? Are you saying you have an app that you've installed but it won't connect to SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer properly right now, but here is a start: You can install fonts during your installation, provided you have the rights to do so (that the font is redistributable - I am not up to speed on the legalese).

[**Maybe read this answer for some font installation details**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080832/how-do-i-disable-font-registration-in-an-installshield-2011-basic-msi-project/46918276#46918276). I have not installed fonts in ages, but give that a go first. It sounds like you need to install a number of things to get your application working on client's PCs. How do you use SQL server? Do you just connect to a remote instance, or do you need to set up custom databases during installation?

What tool are you using to create your MSI?

Comment: i need to set up a custom databases during installation

Comment: You are using Advanced Installer? It has a lot of features to help you with prerequisites.