# How do I disable font registration in an Installshield (2016) msi project?

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-installer, installshield, truetype

We are using InstallShield 2016 for developing our msi. We have an issue wherein, ttf fonts carried by our msi are getting installed in system. We do not want fonts to get registered. We simply want to carry them. But since they get registered, other applications like Outlook, skype, chrome start using them. This creates problems for us during uninstallation.

So our requirement is to carry the fonts, but not to get them registered. Since InstallShield by default registers the ttf fonts, how can we disable this behavior?

What I have tried:

Got some suggestion on stackoverflow but they are not relevant to InstallShield 2016. Please provide us a step-by-step guide.

Comment: Can Direct Editor help me ? If yes, then what is it and where can I find it ?

Comment: [Please see this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080832/how-do-i-disable-font-registration-in-an-installshield-2011-basic-msi-project) (several of them in there). Not sure if just putting them into the Fonts folder will register them. I think they will be if you drop them in there using Windows Explorer. [See this age old thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46918276/129130) (don't have time to re-read it right now).

Answer (score 0):

I would try one or more of the following:

- Condition out the RegisterFonts action in the InstallExecuteSequence (and InstallUISequence if your installations are not silent).  This is as simple as putting "1=0" in the Condition column for the associated action.
- Ensure the Directory of the Component containing the font file(s) is NOT set as FontsFolder.
- Delete all entries in the Fonts table so that they dont register (note that they will still exist in the File table after this).